# No source parameter in real-time response from API checkin

Tags: foursquare

I have an app that
 -  initiates checkins via the API
 -  receives checkin data via the push mechanism

The JSON object returned by an API call contains a source parameter denoting the app. [This actually seems unnecessary, since my app is initiating the API call...]

The corresponding real-time push response sent to my app does NOT have the source parameter included.  Why is that?

I'm attempting to filter out the push data related to my app's checkins, and the easiest way would be to inspect source parameter.  [I could also inspect the checkin ids, and watch for duplicates in the two paths; but that seems unnecessary if the source parameter was always included.]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that particular field isn't currently passed along in our Push API. What exactly are you trying to do?

If you're looking to get real-time notifications about your own app's check-ins, it seems like you don't really need foursquare's push API? You could just have your app send-up the info you want to your own servers at the same time (or immediately after) you check in the user on foursquare, so that you still get real-time info.

If that doesn't work for you, if the user has authorized your application (which will be the case if you're using the User Push API), you can query our check-in detail endpoint (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins) to get that info, and filter away the check-ins you're not interested in.

Comment: My app is actually a server that both does checkins and receives push notifications.  The server endpoint receiving push notifications is only interested notifications from other sources (i.e. it wants to filter out it's own checkins).  It does have knowledge to handle this, but that requires both processes to be aware of each other.  It seemed easier to me if it could just check the notification's source parameter.  And it seemed odd to me that the push object has no source (where it would be useful), while the checkin response has a source (where it is not useful at all!).